# Match data in order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to fetch data from multiple tables according to user search.
But it's not working according to my requirement.

Tables from which I want to fetch record:

1. Street
2. City
3. State

Suppose a user type 'a', Then I want to first search from street table, After that I want to look in City table and in last I want to look in State table.

Tried:

I am using this query to fetch record:

```
SELECT streetObj.street_id AS street_id, CONCAT( streetObj.name,  ' ,    ', cityObj.name,  ' , ', stateObj.name ) namet 
    FROM street streetObj
 LEFT JOIN city cityObj ON streetObj.city_id = cityObj.city_id
    LEFT JOIN state stateObj ON stateObj.state_id = cityObj.state_id
        WHERE (
        streetObj.name LIKE  'a%'
        OR cityObj.name LIKE  'a%'
        OR stateObj.name LIKE  'a%'
       )
       LIMIT 10
```

But this query first searching from state table after that from city table and in last from street table.

How I can change the sequence to look in tables?

Explanation:

Streets:

```
Ram darbar
chawala street
palam street
```

Cities:

```
 Kota
 Ahemdabad
 Jaipur
```

States:

```
 Rajasthan
 Chennai
 Gujrat
```

So I want to see like this when user type 'R' or 'r':

```
Ram darbar,Jaipur,Rajasthan
```

But my query giving me results like this:

```
palam street,Jaipur,Rajasthan
```

Which does not make sense either.

Comment: Move the cityObj.name and stateObj.name from WHERE clause to ON clauses to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (As it is now, it executes as regular inner joins...)

Comment: How will that change the result? I think your question does not tell what exactly you want?

Comment: Because according to my requirement, Street is in city, And city is in state, So i need to show data according to this format;   streetname,cityname,statename,

Comment: Please wait i am giving example of this problem, which will clear my requirments.

Comment: how u come to know that first it is searching in state then city and then street...even query will search in all tables as you are using or condition.

Comment: I give an example . Please look on that. @ZafarMalik

Comment: you have single column for street, city and state or separate in your application in which you are searching?

Comment: In case any of the answers did not work, do post the solution that actually worked

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move the conditions from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` clause like

```
SELECT streetObj.street_id AS street_id,
       CONCAT(streetObj.name, ' ,    ', cityObj.name, ' , ', stateObj.name ) namet 
FROM street streetObj
  LEFT JOIN city cityObj ON streetObj.city_id = cityObj.city_id 
  LEFT JOIN state stateObj ON stateObj.state_id = cityObj.state_id 
  WHERE streetObj.name LIKE 'a%';
```

Per your recent edit in post, you don't actually need the below conditions and should only search in `street` table. You should get the data by the virtue of matching records due to `JOIN`

```
    OR cityObj.name LIKE  'a%'
    OR stateObj.name LIKE  'a%'
```

Comment: by this query if record does not exist in street table then will not search even exist in other city and state tables....

Comment: Sorry, But its not working. Showing data like this    149528 NULL
198701 NULL
304788 NULL

Comment: @ZafarMalik, then that's right. If you place this conditions in `WHERE` then the effect is same as `INNER JOIN` rather a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a3b/1)

**DB Schema**

```
create table streettbl
(street_id varchar(20),
name varchar(30),
city_id varchar(20));

create table citytbl
(city_id varchar(20),
name varchar(30),
state_id varchar(30));

create table statetbl
(state_id varchar(20),
name varchar(30));

insert into streettbl values('street2','palam street','city1');
insert into streettbl values('street1','ram darbar','city1');
insert into citytbl values('city1','jaipur','state1');
insert into statetbl values('state1','rajasthan');
```

**Answer Select Query**

```
 SELECT streetObj.street_id AS street_id, 
CONCAT( streetObj.name,  ' ,    ', cityObj.name,  ' , ', stateObj.name ) namet,
case when streetObj.name like 'r%' then 1
     when cityObj.name like 'r%' then 2
     when stateObj.name like 'r%' then 3
     else 0 end orderby
    FROM streettbl streetObj
 LEFT JOIN citytbl cityObj ON (streetObj.city_id = cityObj.city_id)
    LEFT JOIN statetbl stateObj ON (stateObj.state_id = cityObj.state_id)
        WHERE (
        streetObj.name LIKE  'r%'
        OR cityObj.name LIKE  'r%'
        OR stateObj.name LIKE  'r%'
       )
order by orderby
```

**Output**

```
| street_id |                                namet | orderby |
|-----------|--------------------------------------|---------|
|   street1 |   ram darbar ,    jaipur , rajasthan |       1 |
|   street2 | palam street ,    jaipur , rajasthan |       3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it-

```
SELECT * FROM street AS stt
LEFT JOIN city AS ct ON stt.city_id=ct.id 
LEFT JOIN state AS st ON ct.state_id=st.id 
WHERE 
IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM street WHERE NAME LIKE 'a%')>0,stt.name LIKE 'a%', 
IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city WHERE NAME LIKE 'a%')>0, ct.name LIKE 'a%', 
st.name LIKE 'a%'
)
) LIMIT 10;
```